Rustup problem installing toolchain through Artifactory : SSL certificate not OK
Context
My company is using an Artifactory repository to mirror Rust crates.
So i connected my rustup to this repo and it seems to work fine since it's searching on the good place.
However, i can't use rustup to install rust as the internal proxy of the company ruin all SSL certificate.
A senior dev told me the same happened with Conan and they just deactivate SSL check EVERYWHERE.
Detailled manipulation
I've tried to add in my bashrc the following env var :
export RUSTUP_USE_CURL=1
export CARGO_INCREMENTAL=0
export CARGO_HOME=~/.cargo
export RUSTUP_HOME=~/.rustup
export RUSTUP_HTTPS_REDIRECT=http
export RUSTUP_UPDATE_ROOT=https://<login>:<key>@<repo>/generic-static-rust/rustup
export RUSTUP_DIST_SERVER=https://<login>:<key>@<repo>/generic-static-rust


The login key and repo are the good one.
After trying to install rust by the command
rustup default stable

I face a SSL Certificate error telling me :
SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK (SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate)

Even though the address it is searching for is the good one on Artifactory.
After talking to a senior in my company, he told me that the internal proxy messes up all SSL certificated check and that i must deactivates it.
But after going on this github discussion it seems that developpers don't want to give a way to deactivate it.
https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/1856
The post being a little old, is there today a simple way to do it without :

Changing anything in my internal certificates (i don't have sudo)
Changing the proxy parameters (i'm gonna get killed).

Thanks for you help.

Turned out my company knows about this problem and just created a new proxy with a new artifactory instance to resolve that problem.
After research Rust CAN'T ignore SSL nowadays so if you stub upon this problem, good luck.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
